# opcua-asyncio subscribe_data_change when timestamp changes

Tags: opc-ua

I use a opcua-asyncio (Python) client to get values from a Schneider SCADA.
I created subscriptions for several variables to save those for later use.
The problem is now, that in some rare cases the value of the variables (float) does not change, so the subscription doesnt call the subscription notification.
I tried to subscribe to the timestamp of the vairable, but i could not find the attribute.

```
flow = client.get_node(nodeID_flow)
        acid = client.get_node(nodeID_acid)
        base = client.get_node(nodeID_base)
        water = client.get_node(nodeID_water)
        waste = client.get_node(nodeID_waste)

        nodeIDs = [flow, acid, base, water, waste]

        handler = SubHandler(flow, acid, base, water, waste)
        sub = await client.create_subscription(100, handler)
        handle = await sub.subscribe_data_change(nodeIDs)
```

Is there a way to trigger the subscription notification always when the server variable is set, even if the value stays the same?

Thank you

I already read through the subscription code but could not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if the server handles the filter correctly.

```
filter = ua.DataChangeFilter(Trigger=ua.DataChangeTrigger.StatusValueTimestamp)
handle = await sub._subscribe(nodeIDs, mfilter=filter)
```

Comment: Thank you! The other one works too i guess, but is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this is done in the `opcua-asyncio` API specifically, but in terms of OPC UA, you would create your MonitoredItems with a DataChangeFilter that specified a `DataChangeTrigger` of `StatusValueTimestamp`.

I've observed that not all servers honor this trigger or have the same behavior, though. For example, with the built in OPC UA server of the Siemens S7-1500, you will still only get updates when the value or StatusCode changes because the server does not otherwise update the timestamp internally.